# how to stop file upload process in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

In my application there is a functionality to upload a video file. if a user uploads a big video file and before uploading if he presses a cancel button just panel get closed but uploading process does not stops. I have used a function for stop the uploading process it works fine in Mozilla Firefox but it is not working in i.e (internet explorer) please help me ..

thanks in advance

Comment: Elaborate what you mean by "stop file upload" - client or server?

Comment: Client side or server side or both?

Comment: function cancelUpload() {
            isUploadCanceled = true;
            $find('<%=modalpopupvideo.ClientID%>').hide();
            
            var up = document.getElementById('<%=flpvideo.ClientID%>');
            up.setAttribute("type", "input");
            up.setAttribute("type", "file");
            if (window.stop) {
               
                window.stop();
 
            }
 
            document.getElementById('myHiddenDiv').style.display = 'none';
           
 
        }

Answer (score 1):

I don't think we can stop uploading file if it once started , the only way to stop it before starting only.

However you can look at similar discussion on below link

http://forums.asp.net/t/1303246.aspx/1

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this:

Well, there is probably a much better way to do it but I have found that this stops it (if you can live with the redirect back to the page):

```
FileUpload1.FileContent.Dispose()
Response.Redirect("http://localhost/somesite/Default.aspx")
```